# roslaunch franka_example_contollers joint_position_example_controller_sim.launch

Tags: ros

I get the following error while executing `roslaunch franka_example_contollers joint_position_example_controller_sim.launch`

ERROR:

```
RLException: [joint_position_example_controller_sim.launch] is neither a launch file in package [franka_example_contollers] nor is [franka_example_contollers] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Any solutions for this error ?

Comment: I would check whether the file joint_position_example_controller_sim.launch is actually present where-ever ros currently searches for that file. The error message simply says that this file could not be found, so you will have to add it to the folder where ros actually expects it to be and searches for it.

Comment: Probably you haven't sourced your workspace or not installed the package required.

Comment: @DanielB. the file joint_position_example_controller_sim.launch is present in the specified folder.

Comment: Then it may indeed be about the sourcing. Please checkout the following links:  Maybe that one on setting up ros packages http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment or that one http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage on creating & working with custom packages contains the answer to your problem.

Comment: @DanielB. the .bashrc file contains both source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash and 
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash